# Docker "Login succeeded" but still cannot push to GCP private registry

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, push, gitlab-ci

I am having issues while I am pushing my docker image to my private GCP registry.
I created a new Service account with Owner role from Google Cloud Platform. Then I created a service key and copied the content of the json file (that I downloaded from the Service Account) in the $GCP_SERVICE_KEY variable in Gitlab CI/CD Variables.

This my **.gitlab-ci.yaml** file:

```
image: python:3.6

stages:
  - push

before_script:
  - mkdir -p $HOME/.docker
  - echo "$GCP_SERVICE_KEY" >> "$HOME/.docker/config.json"

dockerpush:
  stage: push
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker build --build-arg MONGODB_URI=$MONGODB_URI -t my_image_name .
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < $HOME/.docker/config.json
    - docker tag my_image_name eu.gcr.io/my_project_id/my_image_name
    - docker push eu.gcr.io/my_project_id/my_image_name
```

When I check the console logs, I see "Login succeeded". But I cannot push to my GCP registry. I checked the Project ID, Roles of my user, everything seems okay. But why do I still see the "unauthorized "error?

```
$ docker login -u _json_key -p "$GCP_SERVICE_KEY" https://gcr.io
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded

$ docker tag my_image_name eu.gcr.io/my_project_id/my_image_name   
$ docker push eu.gcr.io/my_project_id/my_image_name   
The push refers to repository   
Preparing   
Preparing   
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials.  
To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're logging in to `https://gcr.io`, but pushing to `https://eu.gcr.io`

Update your `docker login` command to `https://eu.gcr.io`

Comment: OMG! Such a mistake! Thank you very much!